# SWIFT: Protocol function in static method is not visible on "self"

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, casting

I have a problem to be solved.

This is the code that need to make work:

```
class A: NSObject, RowConvertible {

    /// Initializes a record from `row`.
    ///
    /// For performance reasons, the row argument may be reused during the
    /// iteration of a fetch query. If you want to keep the row for later use,
    /// make sure to store a copy: `self.row = row.copy()`.
    public required init(row: Row) {
        print(row)
    }
}

extension A
{
    public static func currentUser() -> Self?
    {
        // By key
        let userType = type(of:self)
        let user = try! dbQueue.inDatabase { db in

            try self.fetchOne(db, "SELECT * FROM User")
        }

        return user
    }

}

class B: A
{

}

let user = B.currentUser()
print(user)
```

`RowConvertible` is a protocol which contains `fetchOne()` method.

`RowConvertible` is part of GRDB.swift open source library:

```
public protocol RowConvertible {

    public static func fetchOne(_ db: Database, _ sql: String)
}
```

So problem is when I'm trying to call `fetchOne()` static method on self, I'm getting error:

> Type 'Self' has no member `fetchOne`
>   but when I'm calling it on `A` or `B` classes it's OK.

So I need to keep it dynamic and call that method on self.

After all if this work I'll also need to cast returned value to Self type.

Thanks in advance

Gegham

Comment: Can you please post your `RowConvertible` code? And please note, where the error comes and where it's ok.

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look. Error appears when I'm trying to call fetchOne() on self, it's ok when I'm calling it on "A" or "B" classes

Comment: is there a particular reason why you dont want to go like `try A.fetchOne(db, "SELECT * FROM User")` ? "So I need to keep it dynamic and call that method on self." not sure what you mean by that, if you are calling it on A it should always work on any sublcasses

Comment: You mean this line is error `try self.fetchOne(db, "SELECT * FROM User")` ?

Comment: `try A.fetchOne(db, "SELECT * FROM User") ` it will return A type instance, but I need B Type instance.

Comment: @anhtu  yes this line is error

Comment: Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protocol PrintProtocolTest {
    static func printTest()
}

extension PrintProtocolTest {
    static func printTest() {
        print(self)
    }
}

class A: PrintProtocolTest {
}

extension A {
    static func test() {
        self.printTest()
    }
}

class B: A
{

}

B.test() /// <--- print 'B' here
```

You can get the result

> B

Your code is right. Using `self` is ok.

With the return

```
protocol PrintProtocolTest {
    static func printTest()
}

extension PrintProtocolTest {
    static func printTest() {
        print(self)
    }
}

class A: PrintProtocolTest {
    required init() {

    }
}

extension A {
    static func test() -> PrintProtocolTest {
        self.printTest()
        return self.init()  
    }
}

class B: A
{

}

B.test() // <--- return B instance here
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was really helpful to understand why it's not working, but the issue is still exist.

When I'm adding return type on static function `-> Self?` , `self.printTest()` is not working

@anhtu

Comment: @GeghamHarutyunyan I edited my answer and you can return B with that